# Public Company Subsidiary Data

Tags: companies

I have put together a number of tracking systems for public companies. They look at things like news articles and patent filings, and I got my list straight from the NYSE.

What's missing now is subsidiary data.

Public companies have to publish lists of their subsidiaries, and I'm looking to get that list. Thoughts? I usually go to Quandl with these sorts of questions, but they don't seem to have that. Neither does the NYSE.

Let me know if you need any other information.

Best Regards,

-Alex

Answer (score 2):

It looks like OpenCorporates.com has some of this information as part of a *alpha* offering of theirs.

For example, see https://opencorporates.com/companies/us_wa/600413485/statements/subsidiary_relationship_subject which lists Skype, Microsoft Licensing, and others as subsisidiaries of Microsoft Corporation.

Check out [this blog post](https://blog.opencorporates.com/2013/07/11/open-corporate-network-data-not-just-good-but-better/) which mentions the subsidiary functionality