# Is there public database about subsidiaries of companies?

Tags: data-request, companies

I have a list of suppliers I need to consolidate. I want to make explicit that company A is a brand or a subsidiary of company B.

I tried to see if [Wikimedia](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q8419345) or other public sources listed on [Google Dataset](https://toolbox.google.com/datasetsearch) have a structured database with this information, with poor results.

Thanks to [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9187/public-company-subsidiary-data/9194), I know [OpenCorporates](https://opencorporates.com/), but they don't provide easy-to-grab CSV or JSON unless you use the API. I don't know anything about http APIs yet. (I guess I will learn about it if there is no other way.) That's only my problem, but there's more. Sometimes the link between companies is not explicit. For exemple, I know [Rexroth is owned by Bosch](https://opencorporates.com/companies?commit=Go&order=&q=rexroth&utf8=%E2%9C%93), but apart from the name, I couldn't have known if I didn't know Bosch was also a company.

**Is there such a database listing companies and their subsidiaries and/or their brands, at a CSV or JSON format?

Are there any that are free?

Are there any that are open?**

Answer (score 1):

This wikidata query will get you all the subsidiaries of the Walt Disney company known to wikidata:

https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fitem%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20%28wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%29%20wd%3AQ43229.%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%28wdt%3AP127%7C%5Ewdt%3AP199%7Cwdt%3AP749%7C%5Ewdt%3AP1830%7C%5Ewdt%3AP355%29%2B%20wd%3AQ7414.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D

Hopefully, you can adapt it for your parent company of interest.